# After selecting the date of birth in the drop-down box, my age cannot be displayed in real time. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui

**Here’s my front-end page:**

[image]

**Here is part of my code:**

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="text-align: left"><@spring.message "bornDate"/>:</label>
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" name="input-text" id="bornDate" style ="text-align: left"><input id="bornDateTmp" style="width:90px;"  data-bind="value: model.bornDate"/></label>
        <script>
            $("#bornDateTmp").kendoDatePicker({
                format: "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}"
            }).data("kendoDatePicker");
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
...
...
<div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="text-align: left">
            <@spring.message "age"/>:
        </label>
        <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" name="" id="age" style ="text-align: left">
            <span id="ageTmp" data-bind="text:model.age">
                <script>//here，here，here！！！   
                    $("#ageTmp").text(basicInformation.model.age.getFullYear-new Date().getFullYear());
                </script>    
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**In addition, I would like to make a special note that the internal framework of the company is used for data binding:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var basicInformation = kendo.observable({
        model: {
        },
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({async: false});
    Hap.loadViewModel({
        url: '${base.contextPath}/xxentry/people/info/collection/basicInfo',
        model: basicInformation.model
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({async: true});
</script>
```

The problem is, when I choose my date of birth, the age doesn’t show up in real time, but on the chrome console, it works!I've been thinking about it all day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind the change event on the date picker. On change calculate your age and bind it to the observable variable, bind that variable to your age element.

Something like this:

```
<input id="bornDateTmp" style="width:90px;"  data-bind="value: model.bornDate, events: {change: onDateChange}"/>

var basicInformation = kendo.observable({
    model: {
    },
    onDateChange: function(e) {
      var selectedDate = this.model.bornDate;
      var age = //calculate age;
      this.model.set('age', age);
    }
});

<span id="ageTmp" data-bind="text:model.age">
```

Working example: [On change show value](https://dojo.telerik.com/avUKeKEk)